# How to ensure uniqueness in many-to-many relationship table?

Tags: database, join, many-to-many

Users have many roles, roles have many users.

In USERS_ROLES table, have 3 columns: USERS_ROLES_ID, USER_ID, ROLE_ID

Usually USERS_ROLES_ID is just sequentially generated. Someone told me it's supposed to guarantee that user_id and role_id cross product are unique, so the primary key USERS_ROLES_ID should actually be some sort of combination of both USER_ID and ROLE_ID. How is this done, usually? (for example, USER_ID * (big number here) + ROLE_ID)?? Every example I could find uses a naive sequential primary key generation of the many-to-many join table.

Answer (score 1):

Having a sequentially generated USERS_ROLE_ID primary key will not guarantee a unique combination of USER_ID and ROLE_ID.  Adding a unique index on (USER_ID, ROLE_ID) will.

Answer (score 0):

Gerrat is right. I found the full answer here: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/08/23/composite_primary_keys.aspx

> ```
> Create table CustomerProducts
> (
>     Customer_ProductID int identity primary key,
>     CustomerID int references Customers(CustomerID) not null,
>     ProductID int references Products(ProductID) not null,
>     OrderLimit int not null
> )
> ```
>
> This is what I see in perhaps most of the databases that I’ve worked
>   with over the years.  The reason for designing a table in this manner?
>   Honestly, I don’t know! I can only surmise that it is because of the
>   lack of understanding what a primary key of a table really is, and
>   that it can be something other than an identity and that it can be
>   comprised of more than just a single column.  As I mentioned, it seems
>   that many database architects are simply not aware of this fact.
>
> Consider instead the following design:
>
> ```
> Create table CustomerProducts (
>     CustomerID int references Customers(CustomerID) not null,
>     ProductID int references Products(ProductID) not null,
>     OrderLimit int not null,
>     Primary key (CustomerID, ProductID) )
> ```
>
> Notice here that we have eliminated the identity column, and have
>   instead defined a composite (multi-column) primary key as the
>   combination of the CustomerID and ProductID columns.  Therefore, we do
>   not have to create an additional unique constraint.  We also do not
>   need an additional identity column that really serves no purpose.  We
>   have not only simplified our data model physically, but we’ve also
>   made it more logically sound and the primary key of this table
>   accurately explains what it is this table is modeling – the
>   relationship of a CustomerID to a ProductID.